# Having trouble printing a JTable

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable

For my french verb conjugation program I trying to include an option to print a conjugation (in table form)

However the problem is that it prints a blank box, I have read some places that this is because the table is not been visible in the GUI or something like that. The problem is I want the table to be printed without adding it to the GUI at all...

the code for the table:

```
JTable getPrint(String Infinitive)
{
    String [] aPresent = fetchTense(Tense.PRESENT, getID(Infinitive)).split("\n");
    String [] aPerfect = fetchTense(Tense.PERFECT, getID(Infinitive)).split("\n");
    String [] aImperfect = fetchTense(Tense.IMPERFECT, getID(Infinitive)).split("\n");
    String [] aSimpleFuture = fetchTense(Tense.SIMPLE, getID(Infinitive)).split("\n");
    String [] aConditional = fetchTense(Tense.CONDITIONAL, getID(Infinitive)).split("\n");
    String [] aColumnNames = {"Pronoun", "Present"  , "Perfect"  , "Imperfect"  , "Simple Future" , "Conditional"  };
    String [][] aValues = {
                             {"Je"     , aPresent[0], aPerfect[0], aImperfect[0], aSimpleFuture[0], aConditional[0]},
                             {"Tu"     , aPresent[1], aPerfect[1], aImperfect[1], aSimpleFuture[1], aConditional[1]},
                             {"Il"     , aPresent[2], aPerfect[2], aImperfect[2], aSimpleFuture[2], aConditional[2]},
                             {"Elle"   , aPresent[3], aPerfect[3], aImperfect[3], aSimpleFuture[3], aConditional[3]},
                             {"On"     , aPresent[4], aPerfect[4], aImperfect[4], aSimpleFuture[4], aConditional[4]},
                             {"Nous"   , aPresent[5], aPerfect[5], aImperfect[5], aSimpleFuture[5], aConditional[5]},
                             {"Vous"   , aPresent[6], aPerfect[6], aImperfect[6], aSimpleFuture[6], aConditional[6]}, 
                             {"Ils"    , aPresent[7], aPerfect[7], aImperfect[7], aSimpleFuture[7], aConditional[7]},
                             {"Elles"  , aPresent[8], aPerfect[8], aImperfect[8], aSimpleFuture[8], aConditional[8]}
                          };
    JTable pTable = new JTable(aValues, aColumnNames);
    return pTable;
}
```

and I want to print it with the following code:

```
                try 
            {
                JTable pTable = pGUI.getParser().getPrint("Aller");
                JFrame fix = new JFrame();
                fix.add(pTable);
                fix.setVisible(true);
                fix.setVisible(false);
                boolean bComplete = pTable.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, new MessageFormat(String.format("Conjugation of %s", "Aller")), new MessageFormat("Page {0}"));
                if (bComplete) 
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pGUI, "Finished printing", "Printed", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                } 
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pGUI, "Printing Cancelled", "Printing Cancelled", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
            } 
            catch (PrinterException e) 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(pGUI, "An error has occured", "Printing Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
            finally
            {
                pGUI.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
            }
```

Does anybody have any idea what is going wrong here and how can I fix it?

Also as a side note, as this is a blank box I can't be sure but when it prints if a word is too long to fit in the cell will it get shorted to word... for example. And how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

1. For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), because very similair code your posted prints me correct output (to the File or paper), nobody know whats happened in important rest of your code

   possible solution_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***
2. without merging the Arrays together, create 2D array and put that as [JTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames) or JTable(String[][] rowData, String[] columnNames)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29), doesn't matter for testing, sure `Object[][]` is prepared for various data types (`Double`, `Date`, e.i. not only the `String`) in `JTable`
3. all updates must be done on [EventDispatchThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
4. building for a new [TopLevelContainer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) must be done on [InitialThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
5. for both above mentioned points there is about wrapping in `invokeLater`
6. see [JTables tutorial Printing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#printing), try working code example ( [TablePrintDemo.java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TablePrintDemoProject/src/components/TablePrintDemo.java) )
7. `JTables` tutorial ended with link to the lesson [Printing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html)

Comment: hmm... these are the two things that are are relevant. the table is created in the first box and printed in the second, no other parts of the code interact with it. I tested it by putting it into the jFrame and it shows the correct values, it just doesn't print to file or paper correctly.

Comment: 1. for what reason you created "PrintOut_preview", 2. `the table is created in the first box and printed in the second`, there any idea how could be possible,

Comment: when I say box I mean the code from the post :p the table is created in get print, it is just a JTable object. it is given to the code from the other box which does print() on the object. however the printed result is a blank box (the header and footer work though) what code is working for you?